# How would I make a hair particle travel across a surface?

Tags: particles

I am trying to create a scene where several vehicles travel across an uneven surface. To get the effect I'm looking for I put the vehicles into a hair particle system, however I dont know how I would get them to travel across the surface in a decent manner without having to animate each one individually.

[image]

Pretty much all I want is for the vehicles to travel in a straight line forwards over the course of a few seconds.

Is there any way to make the particles travel across the surface in a decent manner?

EDIT: After following the advice of Lemon I have something similar to what I was hoping for, however there are still a few small issues I need to resolve before its finished.

[image]
Sometimes the Vehicles will stop then disappear or disappear into the terrain.

[image]
Or float above it when the landscape dips downwards, as well many of the different particles spawn inside of eachother.

In addition i'm wondering if there is a way to have one of the vehicles to be less common while being in the same particle system or whether it would need to be in its own.

I'm unsure as to how to solve these issues, and am hoping there is a way to without having to have each vehicle be its own mesh.

[image]

Comment: could you describe a bit more the "effect you are looking for", adding some pictures for instance ?

Comment: so you mean you want grass on the terrain and want this grass to bend when the vehicles pass over it ?

Comment: or no... the vehicles are particles and you want them to move, that's it ?

Comment: The vehicles themselves are the particles, I was wondering if there was a way to have them travel without having to have them all meshes with separate animations, The way I was hoping to do so was by putting them into a particle system. Yes that's it

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In this approach :

- The field in green does not emit particles but has a collision setting :

[image]

- The emitter is a band along the field side :

[image]

- The particles are driven straight forward by a curve set as curve guide field :

[image]

- As we want the vehicles to stay above the terrain, their center is set at the bottom part of them :

[image]

[image]

Comment: This helped out a lot and was exactly what I was looking for, however I still have a few issues i'm trying to resolve. For one, the vehicles sometimes float over low spots in the terrain or disappear beneath it even though other particles follow it perfectly. As well the different particles sometimes intersect, meaning they travel in the same place as another particle, I'll leave pictures and the .blend file above.

Comment: @user27370. I understand. A better answer is not in my knowledge (for now I hope).