# Is it possible to rotate hair (object) in timeline?

Tags: animation, particles

I'm trying to animate bugs over my character and can't seem to move them in the timeline using hair particle settings. Could anyone give me advice?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: See here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59031/how-would-i-make-a-hair-particle-travel-across-a-surface

Comment: But I am not sure what you want is possible. If you find something, please be sure to post it here as an answer. Also, CrowdMaster does some amazing stuff, but I have not used it in the manner you require. Find it here: http://crowdmaster.org/

And, also, Ick!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well this technique can be adapted to your situation--it looks like your bugs are largish objects, and I think getting the rotation correct (so the bugs are correctly oriented to the surface) might be hard with any particle system solution.

But if it's useful to you, I can explain how to get an effect like this one:

[image]

The bugs are small symmetrical objects (icospheres) that move using brownian motion and are confined to essentially the surface of the sphere by invisible collision objects (also spheres) just below and above the desired "shell" of motion.

Comment: that might just do the trick. any way you can expand on making invisible collision objects?

Comment: that part at least is easy!  you can simply give the collision mesh a "transparent" shader.

Comment: excellent suggestion. I'm trying out now. thank you!

Comment: that worked. I made the characters skin solid, and an outer shape invisible. the bugs bounce between the objects. worked like a charm. thanks!!

Comment: my pleasure, glad it worked!